# Validating comma separated emails in c# with regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to validate a string of comma separated emails in c#

So far this has worked:

```
^[\W]*([\w+\-.%]+@[\w\-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}[\W]*,{1}[\W]*)*([\w+\-.%]+@[\w\-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})[\W]*$
```

But I need it to not allow the emails if they are separated by multiple commas.
For example:

```
test@test.com,,test@test.com
```

would send back an invalid email and let the user know to retype it in.

Comment: You could split the emails before validating them to simplify the regex.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting the string before you do the regex. you can check for empty strings to see if they had two commas in there back-to-back.

Then you're just left with the normal problem of the email address regex, which, as you can see:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Email+address+validation

has been asked about a bajillion times and there's not really one good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The language I've used is VB.NET, but the methods remain the same:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Module Module1

    Friend Function IsValidEmailAddress(a As String) As Boolean
        Dim isValid As Boolean = False
        Try
            Dim e = New MailAddress(a)
            isValid = True
        Catch ex As FormatException
            isValid = False
        End Try

        Return isValid

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim addressesToCheck = "test@test.com,,test@test.com,notanemailaddress"
        Dim addresses = addressesToCheck.Split(",".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each a In addresses
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} valid: {1}", a, IsValidEmailAddress(a)))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
test@test.com valid: True
test@test.com valid: True
notanemailaddress valid: False
```